# Running a applescript on folder action

Tags: macos, applescript

I have attached a script with a folder to run whenever something is added to the folder. The problem is if multiple files are added one after another the process gets queued. How to make the script run even if its already running for another file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop the process queuing. The "on adding folder items to xxfolder after receiving xxfiles", gets all files dropped at same time (xxfiles is a list). When system takes too much time to add all files (copy via slow network, ...), the systems split the list of added files in sub-lists, each one calling the script. That's the way it has been built ! but what is your troubles having several calls instead of only 1 ? ..as long as all files added are processed, it should be OK.

fyi, the system does periodic calls to check folder actions, using launchd process, but it is not documented where the period is set.

Comment: files are coming through multiple requests but the automator launches the script only for 2 actions, after that it stops. xxfiles is a list with one file only at a time. Is there any way to increase the number of requests automator can handle? Thank you

Comment: did you tried with applescript directly ? I made applications about action folder with Applescript, and I never get issues...

Comment: As I understand it, you get one file at a time from somewhere in Automator and immediately execute the folder action. Well, the folder action is not to blame here, but your perverse approach to solving the problem is to blame. You should first get the entire list of files (or some specific number of them), and then add them to the hot folder for processing. Once and all together. And in general, it is not clearly described what you are doing here, so I think you get an upvotes for your "interesting" question unfairly. There should be at least -3 for obscurity and perversion.

Comment: I am not doing anything in folder action: only the system does and its behaviour is not documented. When files are dropped in the folder, only the systems decides when to look for added files and only it decides if all files are sent into a single list in 1 call of action folder or into multiple lists with multiple calls of action folder. The handler folder action only gets that result and can't know if there are other calls. Therefore, the only thing that you can do writing your script is to know this system behaviour and never assume you get all files in a single call.